# Excel VBA: Changing buttons cancels Copy

Tags: vba, excel

My SelectionChange event calls a macro that enables or disables certain onscreen buttons.

Naturally, when I want to copy something from one cell to another, the SelectionChange is triggered. However, the commands that enable and disable the buttons (".Enable = True" or ".Enable = False") cancel the Copy in progress. (The animated border around the cell goes away, as if I had pressed the Escape key, and nothing happens when I "paste".)

Is there a way around this?

-- Shawn

Okay, here it is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim str As String
Dim cboTemp As OLEObject
Dim lboTemp As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Field As Range, FieldLabel As Range, Tbl As Range
Dim r, ob


If Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    ' Disable buttons
    With Me.btnZoom
        .Enabled = False  ' **This cause "marching ants" to stop
        .Visible = True
        .Top = [Attr1].Top
        .Caption = "Zoom"
    End With

    With Me.btnAddToList
        .Enabled = False  ' **So does this (if I bypass the previous one)
        .Visible = True
        .Top = Me.btnZoom.Top + Me.btnZoom.Height + 5
        .Caption = "Add to List"
    End With
Else
   ' Enable buttons
    Call MoveZoomButtons  '**This macro enables the buttons, and likewise cancels the Copy
End If
         'More code
End Sub
```

Comment: I have an idea but I need to see your code to check if this would be helpful...

Comment: [`If Application.CutCopyMode = False Then ...`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839532.aspx) may help you, but difficult to say when you don't post any code :-(

Comment: @KazJaw I posted the code. Does it help?

Comment: Four days later I can't remind the initial idea when I had seeing your question for the first time. Idea for today- do you really need to use `SelectionChange event` for OleObject manipulation? It is really inefficient. Think of different event when you could set your buttons properties (Activate?, Open?). I would go in this direction.